# Adding a border to a round label image

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a round label with border, containing an image inside. So far I tried setting a stylesheet, overlapping the round image QLabel on a bigger round QLabel with the colored background and changing it's size policy but can't get a non-mediocre result:

With parent background label (marked as  FIX 2):

[image]

With stylesheet set (marked as  FIX 1):

[image]

this is the MRE. in this case I use a blue background  in the same dir:

"steel_blue.png"

[image]

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QImage, QPainter, QPainterPath, QPixmap
import os
import urllib.request

RUNTIME_DIR = Path(os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[0])


class QCustomQWidget(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, video=""):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textQVBoxLayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.textUpQLabel = qtw.QLabel()
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.textUpQLabel.setFont(font)
        color_path = str(Path.joinpath(RUNTIME_DIR, 'steel_blue.png'))
        base_size = 40
        border_width = 2
        # FIX 2 : PARENT LABEL OFFSET BY border_width

        self.textDownQLabelBorder = RoundLabelImage(
            path=color_path, size=base_size + 2 * border_width
        )
        # Overlap filled border-label with image
        self.textDownQLabel = RoundLabelImage(
            parent=self.textDownQLabelBorder, urlpath=video.author_thumbnail, size=base_size
        )
        self.textDownQLabel.move(border_width, border_width)
        #test:
        # self.textDownQLabelBorder = RoundLabelImage(urlpath=video.author_thumbnail, size=base_size)

        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textUpQLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textDownQLabelBorder)
        self.allQHBoxLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.iconQLabel = qtw.QLabel()
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)
        self.textUpQLabel.setStyleSheet('''
            color: rgb(70,130,180);
        ''')

    def setTextUp(self, text):
        self.textUpQLabel.setText(text)

    def setIcon(self, imagePath):
        img = QPixmap(imagePath)
        img = img.scaledToWidth(200)
        self.iconQLabel.setPixmap(img)
        self.iconQLabel.setSizePolicy(
            qtw.QSizePolicy(qtw.QSizePolicy.Maximum, qtw.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        )


# TODO cut off parent border
class RoundLabelImage(qtw.QLabel):
    """Based on:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819033/qlabel-with-image-in-round-shape/50821539"""
    def __init__(self, *args, path="", urlpath="", size=50, antialiasing=True, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Antialiasing = antialiasing
        self.setMaximumSize(size, size)
        self.setMinimumSize(size, size)
        self.radius = size / 2

        if path != "":
            p = QPixmap(path).scaled(
                size, size, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
            )
        elif urlpath != "":
            data = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpath).read()
            pixmap_author = QPixmap()
            pixmap_author.loadFromData(data)
            p = pixmap_author.scaled(
                size, size, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
            )
        ##### POSSIBLE FIX FOR CHILD
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.target = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        else:
            self.target = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        painter = QPainter(self.target)
        if self.Antialiasing:
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        painter_path = QPainterPath()
        if self.parent is not None:
            painter_path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)

        else:
            painter_path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)

        # FIX 1 : STYLESHEET
        # self.setStyleSheet(
        #     f"""
        #         border: 2px solid blue;
        #         border-radius: {size/2}px;
        #         min-height: {size/2}px;
        #         min-width: {size/2}px;
        #         """
        # )
        painter.setClipPath(painter_path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)


class Video():
    """Store video information for ease of use
    """
    def __init__(self, id, title="", time="", author="", thumbnail="", author_thumbnail=""):
        self.id = str(id)
        self.url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + self.id
        self.title = str(title)
        self.time = str(time)
        self.author = str(author)
        self.thumbnail = str(thumbnail)
        self.author_thumbnail = str(author_thumbnail)


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.checkbox_dict = dict()
        self.button_dict = dict()
        listWidget = qtw.QListWidget()
        self.layout().addWidget(listWidget)
        data = {
            'id':
            'MpufpgwiW-0',
            'url':
            'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpufpgwiW-0',
            'title':
            'Lycoriscoris - Seimei (生命)',
            'time':
            '2 hours ago',
            'author':
            'Anjunadeep',
            'thumbnail':
            'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MpufpgwiW-0/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEbCNIBEHZIVfKriqkDDggBFQAAiEIYAXABwAEG&rs=AOn4CLDI8RjBj8u6GvY_bXeBqAOSCRNsqA',
            'author_thumbnail':
            'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnie-87z6V-8oWCHVp4fn4CN17H5if1IqolvJaSL6g=s68-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj',
        }
        my_videos = dict()
        for key, val in data.items():
            if key == "id":
                video_id = val
                my_videos[val] = Video(video_id)
            else:
                setattr(my_videos[video_id], key, val)

        for video_id, video in my_videos.items():
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget(video=video)
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(video.title)
            url = video.thumbnail
            data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
            img_thumbnail = QImage()
            img_thumbnail.loadFromData(data)
            myQCustomQWidget.setIcon(img_thumbnail)
            myQListWidgetItem = qtw.QListWidgetItem(listWidget)
            myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(myQCustomQWidget.sizeHint())
            listWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
            listWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, myQCustomQWidget)

        self.resize(800, 300)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Please try to make your examples as minimal as possible. Your question doesn't seem to have nothing to do with url loading and makes your example really confusing to understand since it has lots of code that's completely unnecessary for what you're asking. That said, the problem is that your "steel_blue.png" image is not squared, while the downloaded image is: since you're using `KeepAspectRatio`, the result is that the background height is smaller. In any case, if you only want to draw a rounded border around an image, your implementation is clearly much more complex than it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to draw a border around a rounded image, using a superimposed widget is certainly not the smartest choice.

What you should do instead is to directly create a QPixmap that *includes* the border.

Here is a revised and cleaned up version of your class:

```
class RoundLabelImage(qtw.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, path="", urlpath="", size=50, border_width=0, border_color=None, antialiasing=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(size, size)

        if path != "":
            source = QPixmap(path)
        elif urlpath != "":
            # you really shouldn't rely on functions that are possibly blocking...
            data = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpath).read()
            source = QPixmap()
            source.loadFromData(data)

        pixmap_size = size - border_width * 2
        p = source.scaled(
            pixmap_size, pixmap_size, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        self.target = QPixmap(self.size())
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        painter = QPainter(self.target)
        if antialiasing:
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self.rect())
        if border_width:
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(border_color))
            painter.drawEllipse(rect)
            rect.adjust(border_width, border_width, -border_width, -border_width)

        painter_path = QPainterPath()
        painter_path.addEllipse(rect)
        painter.setClipPath(painter_path)

        painter.drawPixmap(border_width, border_width, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)
```

You can simply create the instance with the correct arguments:

```
    self.textDownQLabel = RoundLabelImage(
        urlpath=video.author_thumbnail, size=base_size, border_width=border_width, 
        border_color=QtGui.QColor(0, 30, 66)
    )
```

Note that I used the color of the `steel_blue.png` image for the border: since it is just an image with one color and you're always using the same source, using a QPixmap for that is pointless.

Finally, as noted in a comment I put in the code, you really should **not** rely on functions that are possibly blocking (and could even raise exceptions) in a UI element. Downloading *any* content in a QWidget `__init__` will certainly block until loading is complete; this is just wrong to begin with, but if also you have lots of items (or have a slow connection) it makes it even worse.
Do some research on asynchronous downloading (Qt provides the QtNetwork module for these situations, there are hundreds of posts about it), create the items *before* downloading their network content, and then update those contents when downloading is complete, through appropriate signal/slot connections.